# MySQL Function ONLY_NUMBERS

Tags: mysql, function, database-administration, stored-functions

Any help here will be appreciate!

I need a function in MySQL like I have here in my PHP libs, I call that as "onlyNumbers", this function loops all the string filtering numbers and concate as a return string.

I could follow the logic of MySQL syntax and reproduce that, as you see bellow, but there is some thing missing, I think a trick, or some simple step that not comes to my mind.

When run this in MySQL the function is created but when I call that I got this error: #2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Here is my function code:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS ONLY_NUMBERS;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION ONLY_NUMBERS(_STR TEXT) RETURNS TEXT DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
        DECLARE NUMBERS TEXT;
        DECLARE _STR_CHAR CHAR(1) DEFAULT NULL;
        DECLARE _STR_POS BIGINT(20) DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE _STR_INIT BIGINT(20) DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE _STR_ENDS BIGINT(20) DEFAULT 0;
        SET _STR_ENDS = CHAR_LENGTH(_STR);
        STRING_LOOP: LOOP
            IF _STR_POS = STR_ENDS THEN
                LEAVE STRING_LOOP;
            END IF;
            SET _STR_CHAR = SUBSTR(_STR,_STR_POS,1);
            IF _STR_CHAT REGEXP '^[0-9]$' THEN
                SET NUMBERS = CONCAT(NUMBERS, _STR_CHAR);
            END IF;
            SET _STR_POS = _STR_POS + 1;
            ITERATE STRING_LOOP;
        END LOOP STRING_LOOP;
        RETURN NUMBERS;
    END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

When I call **SELECT ONLY_NUMBERS('sadfasdf3423452345234');** I am expecting to see **3423452345234** as result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here we go!

After many, many, many tryies, a got what I expected!

This is a function that return only numbers from a string as argument, I made some improvements with speed, weight, less declares, less memory, etc...

Here are the function, remenber this is using a core MySQL Server you donnot need to install anything:

    `DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS ONLY_NUMBERS;
    DELIMITER //
    CREATE FUNCTION ONLY_NUMBERS(_STR TEXT) RETURNS TEXT DETERMINISTIC
        BEGIN
            DECLARE _NUMBERS TEXT;
            DECLARE _STR_POS BIGINT(20) DEFAULT 0;
            DECLARE _STR_ENDS BIGINT(20) DEFAULT 0;
            SET _STR_ENDS = CHAR_LENGTH(_STR);
            SET _NUMBERS = '';
            WHILE _STR_POS <= _STR_ENDS DO
                IF SUBSTR(_STR, _STR_POS, 1) REGEXP '^[0-9]$' THEN
                    SET _NUMBERS = CONCAT(_NUMBERS, SUBSTR(_STR, _STR_POS, 1));
                END IF;
                SET _STR_POS = _STR_POS + 1;
            END WHILE;
            RETURN _NUMBERS;
        END //
    DELIMITER ;`